# What does du command show?

Tags: linux, terminal, du

I have a normal folder and so when I right click, go to properties and check its data size, it gives 37.3KB.
But when I use the du command, it shows 104KB

Shouldn't these two give the same answer?

Comment: Which desktop system are you using? Gnome? KDE? Unity? Other?

Comment: Most file systems store file data in chunks of fixed size. Therefore, slack occurs as the amount of data and the aggregate size of chunks on disk will coincide only by accident. `du` outputs disk usage (actual number of bytes used on disk), whereas the file properties reflect the payload size.

Comment: Can you explain me a bit more in detail? What is payload size?

Answer (score 3):

It is important to note that hardlinks matter when computing the size of a directory. Two hardlinks to the same file don't take more disk space and share inode number (by definition) but a simple count of file sizes will count them in double.

There's this switch to at least GNU du:

```
   -l, --count-links
          count sizes many times if hard linked
```

Answer (score 1):

The du command recursively descends all directories and subdirectories and always gives you the total contained anywhere beneath.

The properties tab in a GUI doesn't always do this.  Sometimes there's a checkbox (there, or in some other preferences dialog) controlling whether folder sizes are computed recursively, or only give you the top level.  Sometimes, even when the UI does try to compute the size recursively, it takes it a while to update it, so it may show a smaller, temporary number for a while, until it gets around to completing the full recursive search.

So it's not surprising if the UI is giving a smaller number.  Try finding the UI preference for this.

Comment: Thanx :) But that doesnt seem the problem. Because when I do the ls -l command and add the bytes of all the files, then I get the same result as 37  KB

Comment: But are there any subdirectories?  (If not, the answer may be the one reflected to in the comment from @collapsar above.)

Comment: Try running `ls -ls`, and look at both the size in bytes and the size in blocks.  (Beware, though, that the size in blocks doesn't necessarily assume 1k blocks.  You can force it to by setting the BLOCKSIZE environment variable.)

Comment: I can see only one type of size doing that which I think is size in bytes. What are blocks? Any link for the architecture?

Comment: Moreover if @collapsor is right, then does it mean when files are actually of size 37 KN, 104 KB is being used in the disk actually? Isnt it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @[Steve Summit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923896/steve-summit) along with the followup comments overlook some useful information for understanding the problem:

- a simple `ls -ls` will not show *hidden* subdirectories.
- you should see the names of any hidden subdirectories using `ls -las`.
- to see their size recursively, add the `-R` option.
- a better way to show the contents would be with `find . -ls`, which does show subdirectories.
- in either case, `du` shows blocks, which hold "many" bytes
- POSIX's verbiage for blocksize (see [rationale in `ls`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html#tag_20_73_18)) says that the result of `-s` differed across implementations (some may show 1024 for instance):

  > Earlier versions of this standard did not have the -k option, which meant that the -s option could not be used portably as its block size was implementation-defined, and the units used to specify the number of blocks occupied by files in a directory in an ls -l listing were fixed as 512-byte units.
- On the other hand, the standard for [`du`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html) says it should be 512-byte units, just like `ls -l`.

To account for the missing space:

- If you have a lot of very small files, they can use far fewer  bytes than the number of blocks.
- Likewise, you may have hidden files which were not accounted for in the question.
- Finally, some properties dialogs may show only files.  Directories also take up space.

By the way, the `-ls` option of `find` is mentioned in the standard only in the [rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).  But it works with Linux.